# nodejs/express/mongo Have res.render wait until after database search is complete to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having some trouble getting this table to load properly because the page is loading before all the information is passed to my ejs template. Pretty new to all of this and would appreciate any help!

I should note that owneditems is an array of IDs in the user schema.

routes.js:

```
app.get('/profile/:username', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({username: req.params.username}, function(err, user) {
        var newDocs = [];
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('profilemessage', 'No such user exists.');
        } else {
            user.owneditems.map(function(i) {
                Items.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(i), function(err, idoc) {
                    newDocs.push("<tr><td>" + idoc.name + "</td><td>" + idoc.brand</td></tr>");
                });
            }); 
        }
        res.render('profile.ejs', {title: 'Profile', items: newDocs, message: req.flash('profilemessage')});
    });
});
```

Profile.ejs:

```
<!-- content -->
<div class="wrapper row2">
    <div id="container" class="clear">
    <section>
        <% if (message) { %>
            <h4><%= message %></h4>
        <% } %>
        <table id="owneditems" class="sortable">
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Brand</th></tr>
        <% for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {%>
            <%- items[i] %>
        <% } %>
        </table>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>

<% include layoutBottom %>
```

This type of setup works for me on another page, I just can't get it working here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the page is rendered before information is loaded is because`Items.findById` is asynchronous. This means `newDocs` will not return the array of items you're expecting when it's passed to `res.render`.

When you want to load (arrays of) subdocuments with Mongoose, it's best to use [query#populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate). This method will allow you to swap out the item IDs in your  `user.owneditems` array for the actual item document in one go.

I think this would work in your case:

```
app.get('/profile/:username', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({username: req.params.username})
    .populate('owneditems')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        var newDocs = [];
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('profilemessage', 'No such user exists.');
        } else {
            user.owneditems.forEach(function(i) {
                newDocs.push("<tr><td>" + i.name + "</td><td>" + i.brand</td></tr>");
            }); 
        }
        res.render('profile.ejs', {title: 'Profile', items: newDocs, message: req.flash('profilemessage')});
    });
});
```

Also note I switched map with forEach (which is what it seems you're going for given your callback)